# Alinhamento vertical e display inline

Tags: css, css3

boa tarde!

Tenho a página abaixo e por mais que eu tente não consigo fazer o menu ficar em linha com a logotipo.

Onde estou errando?

Outro problema é que a logo e o menu têm altura de `88px` porem a `div` que os abriga tem `120px` de altura e o que eu gostaria é que o bloco `logo/menu` ficasse alinhado `middle` verticalmente em relação à caixa "topo" que os abriga.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color:#F00;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 1000px;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topo {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.logo, .menu {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.logo {
    width:30%;
}

.menu {
    width:69.6%;
}

.corpo {    
    background-color:#CCC;
    border: #000 3px solid;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.menuAbrir, .menuFechar {
    display: none;
}

.menuPrincipal li {
  display:inline;
}

.menuPrincipal li a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:19.6%;
  height:88.19px;
  line-height:88.19px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.menuPrincipal li a:hover {
  color: #F00;
  background-color:#CCC;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topo">
    <div class="logo"><img src="_img/logo.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <img class="menuAbrir"  src="_img/btn-menu.png" width="50px;" title="Abrir Menu" />
      <div class="menuNav"> 
        <a class="menuFechar"><img  src="_img/btn-close.png" width="30px;" title="Abrir Menu" /></a>
        <ul class="menuPrincipal">
          <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="media.php">Media</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="contato.php?form">Contato</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="pedido.php">Pedido</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar uma imagem de como está por favor?

Comment: Não entendi direito sua duvida, rodei o seu código e está alinhado... Pode ser por causa da logo, se puder upar ela também..

Comment: Coloquei no final da pergunta. Note que a logo e o menu estão colados no topo. Mas eles estão dentro uma div "topo" que tem 120px de altura sendo que a logo e o menu têm 88;19px apenas e não consigo centralizar eles

Comment: logo upada no final da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Então, existe vários problemas nesse seu layout, mas eu resolveria esse seu problema colocando um valor fixo no height da div logo, segue abaixo.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #F00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topo {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.logo,
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
  width: 30%;
  height: 88px;
}

.menu {
  width: 69.6%;
}

.corpo {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: #000 3px solid;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}

.menuAbrir,
.menuFechar {
  display: none;
}

.menuPrincipal li {
  display: inline;
}

.menuPrincipal li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 19.6%;
  height: 88.19px;
  line-height: 88.19px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.menuPrincipal li a:hover {
  color: #F00;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUjdf.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <img class="menuAbrir" src="_img/btn-menu.png" width="50px;" title="Abrir Menu" />
    <div class="menuNav">
      <a class="menuFechar"><img src="_img/btn-close.png" width="30px;" title="Abrir Menu" /></a>
      <ul class="menuPrincipal">
        <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="media.php">Media</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contato.php?form">Contato</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="pedido.php">Pedido</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="sobre.php">Sobre</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo - Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kte32a7/)

Da uma procurada sobre display flex, ele facilita muito esse tipo de coisa ;)

Comment: Pois é. mas dessa forma que você fez, note que não foi possível colocar a logo e o menu middle em relação ao topo mantendo o topo em 120px e a logo e o menu em 88px

Comment: Então, acho que consegui! Só acho que não seria a forma mais coerente. Mas consegui. Adicionei  margin-top: 15px; a logo e ao menu empurrando eles para baixo até chegarem ao meio. O que acha?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Então Carlos, ainda não entendi o que você quer! Se quiser colocar o seu código modificado no jsfiddle.net, e mandar o link aqui no comentário eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: Olha, eu tenho uma div com 1000px X 120px ok? Dentro dela eu tenho uma figura de 130x88 e uma outra div de  960x88 que abriga a ul do menu. Correto? O que eu quero é somente alinhar verticalmente essa imagem e essa div (que estão display:inline entre si) dentro da div pai. Mas eu consegui, fazendo 120-88 = 32, 32/2 = 16. Peguei a imagem e o menu e coloquei margin-top: 16px.